# Should I capitalize after a question?

Tags: questions, quotation-marks

Should this sentence be:
"What do I have to do with it?" He asked.

or

"What do I have to do with it?" he asked.

Can it be both?

Comment: "Generally, one would write comma he asked," she said.  Useful site: https://jerryjenkins.com/how-to-write-dialogue/

Comment: @Lambie: That implies you disagree with your link, which supports using a question mark to punctuate a quoted question—not a comma. (Useful site for beginning writers, though.)

Comment: @Roberto Not at all. There are different situations. The article shows exactly what I said in several instances. "What do I have to do with it?", he asked.

Comment: Well, if that's what they said, that's either a typo or really idiotic. Also, my name is Robusto, not Roberto.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**

You do not capitalize after the quoted question

https://www.dummies.com/education/language-arts/grammar/how-to-punctuate-quotations-with-question-marks/